# Handle Multiple request from clients to a PHP page with MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, json

i have a Ubuntu server and a mobile app, i make request with JSON from the mobile app to a php page on the server that handle the request connecting to a MySql DB, but i notice that sometime happen that when the request are a lot in the same time, some request drop, i want know if there is a way to handle multiple request, without lose some.

Comment: Probably there is a connection/time limit somewhere. You should adjust it. But at first you should find what type of resource is limited. (apache, mysql, maybe other components.)

Answer (score 0):

When do the requests drop? Whilst sending a SQL query to the Mysql database?

The cause of this can be either the server itself, which just can't handle that many requests at a time (probably just configured to do so), the script you're using (badly written) or the database.

After you find the cause, start looking for the cure.

Comment: there is way to monitoring when the problem happens?